# Could not cast value of type SINMessage to ChatMessage (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, sinch

Currently trying to bridge the Sinch SDK into my Swift app and I'm running across the following error:

**"Could not cast value of type 'SINMessageRebRTCImpl'" to 'ChatMessage'"**

1) The type **SINMessageRebTyCImpl** is created in the following function located in the AppDelegate.swift file:

```
 func messageSent(message: SINMessage, recipientId: String) {
    self.saveMessagesOnParse(message)
**NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(SINCH_MESSAGE_SENT, object: self, userInfo: ["message": message])** }
```

2) **SINMessageRebTyCImpl** is then passed to the following function located in one of my viewcontrollers

```
func messageDelievered(notification: NSNotification){
let chatMessage: ChatMessage = (notification.userInfo["message"] as! ChatMessage)
self.messageArray.append(chatMessage)
}
```

3) The code then crashes at the second line of the above snippet.

```
let chatMessage: ChatMessage = (notification.userInfo["message"] as! ChatMessage)
```

---

For more information, here is the code for the swift class "ChatMessage" that I am trying to cast too.

```
Import UIKit
Import Foundation

class ChatMessage: NSObject, SINMessage {
    var messageId: String
    var recipientIds: [AnyObject]
    var senderId: String
    var text: String
    var headers: [NSObject : AnyObject]
    var timestamp: NSDate
}
```

(Note, "Import Sinch" does not need to be in the above listed "ChatMessage" class because I have it in the Bridging-Header)

So, what am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: What does the class  look like, please post that class' code if you still need help

Comment: It's the second block of code. :)

Comment: sorry something got cut off when i asked the question, I was looking for this class: SINMessageRebRTCImpl.  That is the one that its complaining about, so wanted to see what that was made of

Comment: Thanks again bolnad. I've updated the question to include what your asking for.  As you can see, the value it attempting to cast to "ChatMessage" is created by the Notification Center but for what ever reason, fast to cast

Comment: The error that your getting is telling me that you have created an object of SINMessageRebRTCImpl type and your trying to cast it as ChatMessage.  However, no where have you shown that this type SINMessageRebRTCImpl has inherited from ChatMessage.  I see that ChatMessage adheres to the SINMessage protocol but that looks to be a different type than SINMessageRebTyCImpl.  So can you post the lineage of SINMessageRebTyCImpl?  That will probably help you to get to your answer. Or Am i missing something?

Comment: From my own search, there actually doesnt seem to be a lineage of SINMessageRebTyCImpl. Rather, the function that I have included in my updated question creates it and then tries to pass it as a NSNotification to ChatMessage class, resulting in the error.

Comment: I guess there's your answer, it never adheres to chat message and has no inheritance so it throws the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay...

So after days of testing workarounds, I found my solution.
The issue seemed to be that, like bolnad suggested, the "SIN" type was not fitting the requirements of the "ChatMessage" class.

So, rather than trying to pass the entire array through a NSNotification variable, I broke it out as follows and set them as NSDefaults

```
let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()    
    chatMessage.senderId = prefs.valueForKey("SENDERID") as! String
    chatMessage.text = prefs.valueForKey("TEXT") as! String
    chatMessage.messageId = prefs.valueForKey("MESSAGEID") as! String
    chatMessage.timestamp = prefs.valueForKey("TIMESTAMP") as! NSDate
    chatMessage.recipientIds = prefs.valueForKey("RECIPIENTID")  as! [AnyObject]!
    self.messageArray.append(chatMessage)
    self.historicalMessagesTableView.reloadData()
    self.scrollTableToBottom()
```

In doing so, I was able to satisfy the "ChatMessage" class without issue!

Thanks to everyone who assisted.

Answer (score 0):

you should use SINOutgoing instead of sinMessage, you dont need to implement the sinmessage protocoll you self.

Edit:

So instead of trying to parse the notificationm pass push to the sinch client adn react to incoming message,

```
id<SINClient> client; // get previously created client 
[client relayRemotePushNotification:userInfo];
```

https://www.sinch.com/docs/instant-message/ios/#localandremotepushnotifications

Comment: Just tested this and there doesnt seem to be a "SINOutgoing" I can place in the class. Can you be slightly more descriptive?

Comment: Still having trouble working out exactly what you are suggesting, though I just realized that it is your github that I am trying to implement in my swift app. I've updated the question to provide more context on what I am trying to do. Perhaps you could take another look at my issue. Thanks

Comment: hello Cjensen
func messageSent(_ message: SINMessage!, recipientId: String!) {
SINMessage not found in Sinch v.1.4.0
tell me how implemnt it